# Find Serial Number of Gateway Without Case

Tags: windows-7, reinstall, gateway, oem

Our Gateway PC crashed, and necessitated a re-install of Windows 7.  We did not have an OEM version of Windows 7 lying around, so I grabbed an old (genuine) copy, and installed that.

Evidently, the product key for the old Windows is being blocked by Gateway.  According to the Microsoft tech, this isn't a big deal, we just need Gateway to unblock that key.  However, Gateway will not even get on the phone (or e-mail, or chat) with you, unless you have either your serial number or your SNID.

The problem is that the motherboard has been moved from the original Gateway case to a different case in order to accommodate a larger power supply.  The only instructions I have to retrieve the SNID are to look on the case, and we no longer have the original case.

So, my question is, where (if anywhere) can I find the SNID for the machine, without looking on the case?  I assume it's got to be on the motherboard, or hidden in the BIOS or something.  I can't find the serial number via the OS, because the OS is not the OEM version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running this from a Command Prompt:

> `H:\> wmic bios list /format`

or

> `H:\> wmic csproduct list /format`.

If the serial is kept in the BIOS it should list it with one of these.

Otherwise, it could be on the motherboard, but you would have to physically check.

Comment: Very cool.  No idea WMI was even a thing.  I did check the mobo, but there was nothing on there that appeared to be an appropriate serial number.  I did not disassemble everything, however, so there's still a possibility it's buried on there somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Source [Using Gateway Identity Card to find the serial number](http://global-download.gateway.com/SupportFiles/HelpDoc/help.aspx?LC=en&BC=Gateway):

> **Using Gateway Identity Card to find the serial number**
>
> For computers that shipped with the Microsoft Windows 7 Operating
>   System, Gateway provides an application entitled Identity Card, which
>   can be used to display the serial number for your computer.
>
> To launch Identity Card:
>
> ```
> Click Start and then All Programs
> Click on the Gateway folder
> Click on Identity Card
> ```
>
> **Alternatively, the serial number will be located in the BIOS which can be entered by pressing the F2 key when powering on the computer.**

Comment: The first part of your answer isn't really relevant, as the Windows install is not the OEM version anymore.

Comment: Yeah, the same section of the FAQ included the BIOS alternative. I just quoted the whole FAQ for consistency. The serial number should be enough for Gateway.

Comment: Also works - prominently displayed in the BIOS.  I read about that fix during my initial digging, but when I saw the referenced program had to already be installed, I didn't bother reading to the end of the section. :)